Proving Closure Under Multiplication in a Set with Specific Properties
I encountered a problem where I needed to prove that a set ( A ) is closed under multiplication, given the following properties:

$0 \in A$
$1 \in A$
If $x, y \in A$, then $x - y \in A$
If $x \neq 0$, then $\frac{1}{x} \in A$
If $x, y \in A$, then $x +y \in A$

To prove that $xy \in A$ for $x, y \in A$, I followed these steps:

If $x \neq 0$ and $x \neq 1$, since $x - 1 \in A$ and $x \in A$:
$
   \frac{1}{x-1} \in A \quad \text{and} \quad \frac{1}{x} \in A$
Therefore:
$\frac{1}{x-1} - \frac{1}{x} = \frac{x - (x-1)}{x(x-1)} = \frac{1}{x(x-1)} \in A$
Consequently:


$
   x(x-1) \in A \quad \Rightarrow \quad x^2 - x \in A \quad \Rightarrow \quad x^2 \in A
   $

Similarly for $y$:
$
   y^2 \in A
   $

Since $x + y \in A$, we have:
$
   (x + y)^2 \in A$
Thus:


$ (x + y)^2 - (x^2 + y^2) = 2xy \in A
   $

Therefore:
$ 
   \frac{1}{2xy} \in A$
This implies:


$  \frac{1}{2xy}+\frac{1}{2xy} = \frac{1}{xy} \in A \quad \Rightarrow \quad xy \in A
   $
My Questions:

Why does this algebraic manipulation prove that $xy \in A$?
Is there an alternative logical approach to prove the closure under multiplication for set $A$?

Any additional insights or corrections to my approach would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Isn't $A$ just the set of rationals?

After all, every integer is in $A$, so every reciprocal of every non zero integer is in $A$, and that gets you all the rationals.

That's a great observation! The properties given for set $ A $ do indeed align with the properties of the set of rationals $( \mathbb{Q} )$. However, the problem does not explicitly state that $ A $ is the set of rationals. It only provides certain properties that $A $ must satisfy. My goal is to prove that $ A $ is closed under multiplication based on these properties alone.

I sketched a proof that $A$ is the rationals.  That proves it is closed under multiplication.

@lulu The rationals is the smallest subset of the reals satisfying these properties, but there are many others, and a priori some of the others may not be closed under multiplication.

I’m not sure why $1$ is a question. You have literally written down a proof that $A$ is closed under multiplication (except you should observe in step $1$ that if $x = 0$ or $x = 1$, the obviously $x^2 \in A$, and in step $4$ you need to consider the case where $xy = 0$, but those are all minor edge cases). Is there a step in the proof that you’re not sure about?

(Technically, I suppose the proof also depends on the base field having characteristic being not $2$. But I assume the question is about a set of reals or complex numbers, so that won’t be an issue.)

@AlexKruckman $A$ is clearly contained in the rationals.  ${0,1}$ are rational and none of the operations can produce can irrational out of rationals

@lulu The question never says $A$ is the closure of ${0, 1}$ under the operations, just that it is closed under them. By your logic every field would be $\mathbb{Q}$.

@DavidGao  How so?  I agree that I assumed that $A$ was in $\mathbb R$.  The OP should specify if some other setting was involved (we need arithmetic operations after all).  If you assume that $A\in \mathbb F$ for some field $F$, then you still get that $A$ is contained in the prime field of $F$.  None of the operations can take you out of that prime field and $1+1+\cdots +1$ gets you every element in the prime field.

@lulu “None of the operations can take you out of that prime field”. I agree. But you do know the difference between “$A$ is the closure of ${0, 1}$ under the operations” and “$A$ is closed under the operations”, right? You’re only showing the closure of ${0, 1}$ under the operations is $\mathbb{Q}$, which is absolutely true. But $A$ could be strictly larger, for example, $A = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ easily satisfies all the conditions listed.

@DavidGao  Ah, agreed.  Yes, I assumed that $A$ was the set of values that could be produced out of $0,1$ by repeated use of the rules.  I agree that the OP did not assume that, so I will delete my posted "solution".  Thanks.

See also here and here on rings whose units $\cup,{0}$ comprise a field.  $\ \ $
